# Is there a better way to write my makefile?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I have this makefile

```
# Compiler and flags
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Iinclude

# Source and object files
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

# Dependency files
DEPS = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,obj/%.d,$(SOURCES))

# Include dependency files
-include $(DEPS)

# Build object files from source files
obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) $<

# Build library from object files
libui.a: $(OBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^
    ranlib $@
    copy vui.hpp include/vui.hpp

# Clean object files and library
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    del obj\*.o obj\*.d libui.a
```

and this is my workspace:

```
workspace
├── include
│   ├── UI_Button.hpp
│   ├── UI_CheckBox.hpp
│   ├── UI_Console.hpp
│   ├── UI_ScrollBar.hpp
│   ├── UI_Slider.hpp
│   ├── UI_TextBox.hpp
│   └── vui.hpp
├── src
│   ├── UI_Button.cpp
│   ├── UI_CheckBox.cpp
│   ├── UI_Console.cpp
│   ├── UI_ScrollBar.cpp
│   ├── UI_Slider.cpp
│   └── UI_TextBox.cpp
├── obj
│   ├── UI_Button.o
│   ├── UI_CheckBox.o
│   ├── UI_console.o
│   ├── UI_ScrollBar.o
│   ├── UI_Slider.o
│   └── UI_TextBox.o
├── libui.a
└── Makefile
```

Now that makefile has built everything I got an error

```
copy vui.hpp include/vui.hpp
The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:24: libui.a] Error 1
```

and when I try to remake I need to delete everything because it only checks UI_Button.o and says it is up to date even if I change any other .hpp or .cpp file it doesn't want to rebuild. Is there a a way I can fix these two errors? the vui.hpp just includes all other headers.

Comment: sorry that was a typing error in my question on my part the file name in vui.hpp not UI_vui.hpp

Comment: The main problem is the rebuild. It doesn't care if any of the files change as long as the UI_Button is unchanged.

Comment: maybe better to have `DEPS = $(wildcard obj/*.d)` and `include $(DEPS)`. But also can you  check that all the `obj/***.d` files exist - and what do they contain? (perhaps print an example of `obj/UI_TextBox.d`?

Comment: Also it looks like `-include $(DEPS)`   is included before your first/default target - better to put this further down or at the end - otherwise your default target (just running `make`) might give you unexpected results)

Comment: Any particular reason to write new makefiles in 2023?

Comment: @Osyotr It's 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `copy` or `del` is, but I assume `copy a b` copies a file `a` to `b`. However, this recipe:

```
# Build library from object files
libui.a: $(OBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^
    ranlib $@
    copy vui.hpp include/vui.hpp
```

does not depend on `vui.hpp`, nor do I see any rule to create `vui.hpp` in your source-root, nor do I see it listed in the files you state you have in your source tree. So, there just is no such file.

If you want to hang on to that command, don't have it running in a completely unrelated recipe. Have an extra recipe for it:

```
include/vui.hpp: vui.hpp
    copy vui.hpp include/vui.hpp
```